# How to create a slideshow of different views?

Tags: 7, views

I am trying to create a slideshow of different [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

I am thinking that the ["view field"](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) might work with ["views slide show"](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) - possibly sending the "view result counter" through as an argument. I am struggling though as I'm not sure this is a readable contextual filter when it reaches the "view field" view.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? If the "view result counter" is readable, what contextual filter should I add in the "view field" view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current approach will not work because View Fields View will insert the **same** view for each and every row/slide.

---

Here is what you need to do. For example: You want 4 slides.

Create a Slideshow View of Articles or something that has 4 or more content. Then set the view results to 4, so it only shows 4.

Now add a **Global: View Result Counter** and exclude from display.

[image]

Add a **Global: Custom Text** and for text put:

```
[counter]
```

[image]

In your view preview you should see numbers

```
1
2
3
4
```

Now we are going to override these (the custom text), and replace them with views in **template.php** (located in `/sites/all/themes/yourtheme/`) add the following code:

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_views_view_fields($vars){

  if ($vars['view']->name == "view_slideshow_name" && $vars['fields']['nothing']->content == 1) {
    $vars['fields']['nothing']->content = views_embed_view('view_name', 'block_1'); 
  }
  else if ($vars['view']->name == "view_slideshow_name" && $vars['fields']['nothing']->content == 2) {
    $vars['fields']['nothing']->content = views_embed_view('view_name', 'block_2');
  }
  else if ($vars['view']->name == "view_slideshow_name" && $vars['fields']['nothing']->content == 3) {
    $vars['fields']['nothing']->content = views_embed_view('view_name', 'block_3');
  }
  else if ($vars['view']->name == "view_slideshow_name" && $vars['fields']['nothing']->content == 4) {
    $vars['fields']['nothing']->content = views_embed_view('view_name', 'block_4');
  }
}
```

- replace **yourtheme** with the actual name of your theme
- replace **view_slideshow_name** with the name of your view slideshow.
- replace **view_name** with the name of the view that you want to show
- replace **block_1** with the [machine name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbNIb.jpg) of your view

Lastly, in Drupal, clear/flush your Cache to see the changes.

> **Note:** The changes will show up when you see the slideshow in your page and not in the view preview.

---

### Forgot to mention that you need to uncheck provide/add wrappers and classes.

[image]

### Also, for both of your fields, do as below

[image]

> It seems odd that you have to list the block name of the view you want to insert but not the block name of the view you are overriding.

That's because in my case I did not plan to add more blocks or pages to my view. When you do not specify, it affects all pages or blocks that are from your view.

But if you want to be specific here is how:

```
function bartik_preprocess_views_view_fields($vars){ 

  if ($vars['view']->name == "rotator" && $view->current_display == 'block_1' && $vars['fields']['nothing']->content == 1) { 
  
    $vars['fields']['nothing']->content = views_embed_view('checking_home', 'block_1'); 
    } 
  
  else if ($vars['view']->name == "rotator" && $view->current_display == 'block_1' && $vars['fields']['nothing']->content == 2) { 
  
    $vars['fields']['nothing']->content = views_embed_view('home_outstanding_issues', 'block'); 
    } 
  
}
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for you response. I have been tinkering but cant get it to work. this is what I have added in the template.php

function bartik_preprocess_views_view_fields($vars){

  if ($vars['view']->name == "rotator" && $vars['fields']['nothing']->content == 1) {
    $vars['fields']['nothing']->content = views_embed_view('checking_home', 'block_1'); 
  }
  else if ($vars['view']->name == "rotator" && $vars['fields']['nothing']->content == 2) {
    $vars['fields']['nothing']->content = views_embed_view('home_outstanding_issues', 'block');
  }
 }

Does anything look incorrect?

Comment: function bartik_preprocess_views_view_fields($vars){

  if ($vars['view']->name == "rotator" && $vars['fields']['nothing']->content == 1) {
    $vars['fields']['nothing']->content = views_embed_view('checking_home', 'block_1'); 
  }
  else if ($vars['view']->name == "rotator" && $vars['fields']['nothing']->content == 2) {
    $vars['fields']['nothing']->content = views_embed_view('home_outstanding_issues', 'block');
  }
 }

Comment: @user30505 your code looks good to me, did you remember to flush the cache?

Comment: sorry, I'm still struggling to get it working :-( I would love to help out and identify what I have wrong but as I have zero PHP experience I am of little help here. It seems odd that you have to list the block name of the view you want to insert but not the block name of the view you are overriding. I am using panels and a sub theme but I don't think this makes a difference. I tried removing the sub theme and using a "page" view of the slide show but still no joy.

Comment: @user30505 I have updated my answer, unchecking those boxes and using the new code I provide below should work now. Remember to flush your cache. for `$view->current_display == 'block_1'` I just put block_1 as a dummy, put your actual [machine name](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NbNIb.jpg) there.

Comment: Thanks, I'm back in the office Thursday. Will try again then.

Comment: Thanks loads, working great, very much appreciate your comments and assistance. X